# System.ini on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive-cache

[AnalogX CacheBooster](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/System/cb/Freeware.htm) supposedly [works on Windows 7](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/increase-or-decrease-your-hard-drive-cache-memory-with-cachebooster/) and allows you to change the system file cache size.

I've found that it edits the `C:\Windows\System.ini` file with values like:

```
[vcache]
minfilecache=430592
maxfilecache=2097151
chunksize=1024
```

However, anything I find online about `System.ini` seems to be more from the Win95-era....

Does this actually do anything on Windows 7 (or even XP)?

Comment: It could be there for backward compatibility. Old software may still look for it, so it's there.

Comment: @Traveling: So CacheBooster is bogus?

Comment: No, never said that. I meant the ini file is there for backward compatibility. CacheBooster may just be covering all bases in case its run on an older system.

Comment: @Traveling: Oh so you mean it might be doing something else I'm not detecting?

Comment: I'm sure it does. Probably writes to the registry, and may even touch other system files to achieve what it's promising to do.

Comment: @Traveling: I monitored it with Process Monitor and the only change it makes anywhere is the change I have above.

Comment: I'd use RegMon to see what it writes to the registry.

Comment: @Traveling: Process Monitor monitors the disk *and* registry. It supercedes RegMon. :P (Btw, gonna sleep.)